# poetry: command not found

Tags: python, bash, python-poetry

I have **Poetry** installed, and have a `poetry.lock` in the same cwd.

I want to perform `poetry update/install`.

---

**Why can I not install poetry dependencies?**

Terminal:

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key/compositekey/tests$ pip3 install poetry
Requirement already satisfied: ...
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key$ ls
Dockerfile  azure-pipeline-composite_key.yaml  compositekey  docs  poetry.lock  pyproject.toml
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key$ poetry update
poetry: command not found
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key$ poetry install
poetry: command not found
```

---

---

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: The question is, where did `pip3` install `poetry`, and is that directory in your `PATH` variable?

Comment: Ohh, I hate PYTHONPATH ;( Couldn't tell you. How do I find out where a package is installed to?

Comment: add this to your .bashrc : PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"

Comment: It's the `PATH` not the `PYTHONPATH` that matters for whether _bash_ can find `poetry`; the `PYTHONPATH` controls only what _Python_ can import.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to know where the module is installed (which will give us a good clue about where the shell wrapper lives), a good place to start is `python -c 'import poetry; print(poetry.__file__)'`

Comment: @Philippe, unless the OP used `sudo` during the first `pip3 install`, it's unlikely to be in `/usr/local/bin` (well-designed operating systems and package managers don't let unprivileged accounts write to that directory out-of-the-box; the only widespread one I know that's so poorly thought-through as to permit such a thing is Homebrew, and consequently, I strongly advise against its use). More likely we have a location under their home directory.

Comment: @StressedBoi69420, ...if you think you installed it in the first place with `pip3` and without `sudo`, then `find "$HOME" -name poetry -print` is a good place to start in trying to locate the executable. Once you have a location, make sure that directory is in your PATH.

Comment: `python3 -c 'import poetry; print(poetry.__file__)'
/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/__init__.py` @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @StressedBoi69420, great; do you have a `poetry` executable in `/home/me/.local/bin`? (It's a guess, but a fairly informed one).

Comment: Hypothetically, I should be able to do: `poetry run python3 <filename>.py`,`poetry install` or `poetry update`. I can't.

Comment: You can only run `poetry <anything>` if you have a directory containing a `poetry` executable in your `PATH` (or a shell function or alias by the same name, but those aren't relevant here). That's why we're trying to figure out where that directory is, so we can amend your `PATH` appropriately.

Comment: Ah sorry, ok @CharlesDuffy

Comment: `$ find "$HOME" -name poetry -print
/home/me/.local/bin/poetry
/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry`

Comment: Great, that confirms the earlier guess. `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin` should fix your problem for the duration of the shell session in which it's run.

Comment: That's allowing me to do `poetry install` :). Thanks! What would be a permanent solution, for new shell sessions? Can always just copy and paste your last command ^